# Overriding the return View when it is a mobile site to use a different view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Would it be possible to override the call to:

```
return View()
```

To append the string "mobile_" to the name of the view file, in other words, instead of calling the view "index.aspx" use "mobile_index.aspx".

Somewhere else I guess in a before action fires event I will check if its a mobile application, set a flag.  So if the flag is set, it should append "mobile_" to the view name.

And I want this done at the controller level and not have to do this for each action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792205/asp-net-mvc-separate-mobile-views-using-same-controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve has been implemented by Stackoverflow.
I was trying to do the same recently and I bumped into this [article](http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/17/mobile-views-in-asp-net-mvc3/).
It's really interesting and goes on the same road you want to follow.

At the end I decided to implement for my implementation to go this [way](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/02/25/mobile-enabled-web-apps-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery-mobile.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The linked duplicate question has a number of options for implementing automatic mobile device detection; Scott Hanselman's is MVC3-specific so I'd start there.

However, to implement your exact solution is also possible. Create your own base controller class and override the View() method to do what you want before calling into the base View. Then derive all your site controllers from that.

The source code for MVC3 is published my MS so you should be able to see exactly what the base View() uses to figure out the view name, and "fix" it to be mobile_whatever.